# How to prevent img tag increases the height of it's parent

Tags: html, css

I have a `<form>` containing several `<input />` fields. On some of these fields I have added a calendar widget for selecting a date - that is working without any problems.

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.img {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example #1 (table)</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
      <img class="img" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Example #2 (div)</h1>
<div>
  <input />
  <br/>
  <input />
  <br/>
  <input />
  <img class="img" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
  />
</div>
```

My problem is a calendar icon next to the `<input />` field. The height of all rows containing the calendar icon are increased by a few pixel:

[image]

How can I prevent this? I already set the `width` and `height` of the `<img>` to `20px` and the `<img>` isn't higher than the `<input />`.

Unfortunately I have to change the position of the `<img>` otherwise it would be starting a few pixel above the `<input />`.

Comment: You could add "float: left;" to your input and your image to get rid of that space.

Comment: Does the image contain margin in white? Reducing the height of the image also reduce space between inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much. `float: left;` solved it.

Comment: I already set the height of the image to 20px and margin and padding was set to 0px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `position:relative; top:5px;` on your image, use `vertical-align:middle;` on both the `input` and the `img`.

The `vertical-align` rule determines how `inline elements` of different heights should be positioned vertically on a `line`. The `input` and `img` elements have different `vertical aligns` by default, which is why you need to set it manually to achieve your desired effect.

Using `top:5px` pushes the image down by 5px from the top, which resulted with extra space between your lines. So remove that bit. Using `top` to center elements vertically is a bad idea anyway, as you may have images that are of slightly different sizes and it is more prone to getting disaligned again when more elements are introduced.

Demo:

```css
html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
img {
  width: 20px;
}
img, input{
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example #1 (table)</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input />
      <img class="img" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
      />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h1>Example #2 (div)</h1>
<div>
  <input />
  <br/>
  <input />
  <br/>
  <input />
  <img class="img" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAADXElEQVR42rXUy4/bVBQG8NmwYVMkNghVQiBgAQukLvh3WIBAgOgOsWEBu4oVC1ggBAIEFFRAGihUVJ0yTdxOM5mkedhOMomdtx/X79iJU2eSr+fa08BkRuxq6VOUG+Wnc33OvVtbj+KRq3ffqZWE7ep+breyn9up8hz8f2oPU8zt1ku3/5AqhffWIMdso49kPkMcLzCLE0xnCSJKOE0woQRRAj/M4lHcSQKH4voT6KMuCL26BnllHAMSLKwDJKyIuVlArO9hqt1GNMojHN5C0P8HfvcmXPUGnM512J2/YbsOHC8AVXprDfJt8soWdgnWz8/DuvISfb4IdvlZsB/Og33/FMzvnoT5zTmYXz8O46vHoH+5Bf2zLRita2B+gvpB/uZ/K9zh20ysEuzfLsDPvYFAeBtB/q2NvJmFfvN3X4PxBaHNv2B69zdAern8nc3NfbCfnoO3/WoKO7++AueXl9NqnSsvwLr8DKwfz1OehvntEzCpQq1xFYZLYGkDDMMQi0hHJH2OvnAJfuVTWIVLGOU/Qlj5BL2d9+Htfwwz/wGGNy5iUvwQ3T9fR1+pwbAnp8GJ72BJbVlR5F6AmL5YwRHU8QT8kdoa4iOAeTGUAcvWGh10Ri4Mk50GA8/BgpDlcolGZ0Cjcx+W7aDbG2K1WkGWZcxmMzBTh9Jp0doScu0A7T6DblqnQZ/A5OgYPOwSOAezbKi9fgZKYgYaGpR2IwOrBRz2DGiGBXET9Fwb88Ux2FIykDGo3W76Z0mqEjglcAzlUE7XGgS2ugbG+hmg69igyTkG2wTGBJpQVSUD6/cwmxKojwgU12BD1THSGYHCSdAhkCYn216zSUdwDouDSidrQK2EmCq0jBHUw3q61qgVICsahtoGyA+5Y1uI4hWSJEkbEEURDL69ThOLRQKpWkQ4CWBofSitWrrGK5QV/WzQpTPJ50mWJYj1KjWhStssQ6wU026K5TvUhLuQKnsQ791JMbEs0JaNM8BSbtfzPLAgwUD3MDA89MY0MmPq8shKR6NNs8cb0KQ0KLwyjjWHIb1DPjbCv5dDrSxsa3QFOa5Ls2en42IyGwaz0hnj4aPBu8kbwCt6GI4N+urJ64u28G69LPzOryB+yNOUTkZcRzgRXhnH6uW9i4/k9n8AX5hil9Pvm0cAAAAASUVORK5CYII="
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining the cause of my problem. I think changing the `vertical-align` seems to be a better way instead of using floating, isn't it?

Comment: I'd say so personally. It allows you to add `inline-elements` that may not be exactly 20px and still have them align. Besides, when using `float` you may have to use empty elements with `clear:both` to avoid issues with floated elements. You may also use `line-height` to force to line to a certain height, if you have higher elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want answer then use this code :

```
 <style>
    html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.img {
  float:left;
  margin-left:4px;
}
.inpt_cls {float:left;}
   </style>
```

To have icon in same line, use `float:left` on both element so they will be in one line and replace `<input />` this to `<input class="inpt_cls"/>` so particular css will apply on input class.

and you will get what you want. Hope it help or let me know if there is any issue. Ty

Comment: Maybe you could expand your answer by explaining why you are applying those styles. It might seem trivial to you but some of the readers might not understand what you are doing here.

Comment: Besides that, the reset styles on the `html` element might not be a good idea if the other elements in the page are not assuming them.

Comment: @mastazi, i don't know why you are targeting on me but i have used the css of op and edited mine.please also read the question of op before giving that type of comment. Thanx

Comment: I'm not targeting you and I'm sorry if it seemed that way, I was just suggesting that you edit your answer, you did that and now it will be useful for other readers in the future, not just the OP

Comment: @mastazi, oh well then sorry as m always getting rude people so i commented..sorry for my bad and thanx for pointing me in good way..:)